# Getting raw text from lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

Trying to get the text from an HtmlElement in lxml. For example, I have the HTML read in by

```py
thing = lxml.html.fromstring("<code>&lt;div&gt;</code>")
```

But when I call `thing.text` I get `<div>`, meaning that lxml is translating escape characters. Is there a way to get this raw text, i.e., `&lt;div&gt;`? This is part of the output when I do `lxml.html.tostring(thing)`, but that includes the opening and closing tags which I don't want.

Tried calling `tostring` with a few different encoding options but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked into it a bit closer:

- `cdef tostring(...)` in `src\lxml\etree.pyx` - see https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx
- `cdef _tostring(...)` in `src\lxml\serializer.pxi` - see https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/serializer.pxi

and I couldn't find anything that would suggest you could get the escaped string by configuring the parameters of the `tostring()` function. It seems like it will always return the unescaped string maybe due to security concerns ...

The way I see it, you would have to use another function such as `html.escape` to get the escaped string:

```py
import lxml.html
from html import escape as html_escape

thing = lxml.html.fromstring("<code>&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;</code>")
raw_thing = lxml.html.tostring(thing, method="text", encoding="unicode")  # <div>MY TEST DIV</div>
escaped_thing = html_escape(raw_thing)  # &lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;

print(escaped_thing)
```

Essentialy what you are looking for is `lxml.html.tostring(root, method='text', encoding="unicode")`:

```py
import lxml.html

thing = lxml.html.fromstring("<code>&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;</code>")
output = lxml.html.tostring(thing, method='xml', encoding="unicode")

print(output)   # <code>&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;</code>
```

The problem is that it cannot separate the root element from its child in `<code>&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;</code>`

However with a different approach you can get the desired output:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

thing = """
<code>&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;<div>&lt;div&gt;AAA&lt;/div&gt;</div><div>&lt;div&gt;BBB&lt;/div&gt;</div></code>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(thing)
root_text = ET._escape_attrib(root.text)
print(root_text)

for child in root:
    child_text = ET._escape_attrib(child.text)
    print(child_text)
```

The code above prints out:

```
&lt;div&gt;MY TEST DIV&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;AAA&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;BBB&lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this get just the text attached to this one html element? Or will it retrieve text from the child elements as well?

Comment: Actually, when I tried running this locally I wasn't able to get the raw string (it still escaped). What version of lxml is this in?

Comment: Note that the OP is using `lxml.html`, not `lxml.etree`.

Comment: Is there some way to turn an HtmlElement into an etree element somehow? In the latest code block you assign the text explicitly, but that won't work if the Element is already created.